# How many people did Alexandr Sergeevich Pushkin kill in duels before d'Anthès stopped him?

Tags: biography, alexander-pushkin

I'm wondering, if duels were popular in Russia in Pushkin's times. 37 is a high number of years and Pushkin did shoot many humans, before was shot downed by d'Anthès.

I'm trying to `grep` [ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) with "дуэль" - and there is only one... and it is only little paragraph about his death.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pushkin didn't kill (or even wound) anybody in duels before he was killed in one.

There is a full list of Alexander Pushkin's duels in Rina Tim's article [Alexander Pushkin’s Duels](https://rinatim.com/2016/12/03/alexander-pushkins-duels/). There were 26 of them. Most of them were called off, and in several of the others, Pushkin did not shoot. In two of them, both participants shot and missed (although it's not stated whether they were trying to miss or not). The only one where a bullet hit a participant was the one where Pushkin was killed.

Comment: "Most disputes die, and no-one shoots"

Comment: So, your answer is 0? Zero?

Comment: The answer is zero. Pushkin never even wounded anybody in a duel before being killed in one.